# Run function inside setInterval once before repeating

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks for the change of day from last visit every 5 minutes when the page is loaded, using setInterval. Also there is data associated with each day that is to be stored in the local storage.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(newDay()) {
     today = getTodaysDay();
     // store required data in the database
  }
}, 30000);
```

The problem is, when the day changes and I log the data from the database for that day, I see " undefined " for 5 minutes, that is until the function inside the setInterval is run. Is there a way to fix this? I tried copying whatever is inside setInterval and placing it above `setInterval(function()...` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is the issue that you're missing the data from the first part of each day when it's uploaded via this function? If so, I think we'd need to know more about how the data is collected.

Comment: The function is not run for first five minutes of the day that results in no storage/upload at all. That is the problem. I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: So the problem is in the `newDay()` function, not your setInterval. How is `newDay()` being calculated? Or maybe you just need to calculate the data first before storing it if it's fired before the data is calculated for the day.

Comment: setInterval(function x(){console.log("ping"); return x;}(), 1000);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking for, but this should do what you want:

```
// Declare the function first:
function dostuff() {
  if(newDay()) {
     today = getTodaysDay();
     // store required data in the database
  }
}

// Call it once to begin with
dostuff();
// Then create an interval to run the function every 30 seconds:
setInterval(dostuff, 30000);
```